# How to customize the Dashboard in Alfresco?

Tags: customization, alfresco, dashboard

I have created a user, as an admin. And when I login as the created user, I tried to customise the Dashboard i.e deleted some of the Dashlets like My Site, My Activities.

However, when I click on ok Button, it shows a message saying  "Saving Configuration". But the Dashboard stuffs does not get changed. Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Any messages in the log? Are any other users affected? What specific version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

(As Jeff said, please check `alfresco.log` or Tomcat's `catalina.out` for related errors. In the following I will assume that no errors appear in these files.)

This should work, so what you are facing looks like a bug.

Please search [JIRA](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira) for any similar issue, and if you can't find any, please fill a new issue, but be sure to mention what Alfresco version you are using, and attach your log files.